# Is it possible in SSRS report to show a pop-up child report showing detail of the parent report, if yes then how?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, business-objects

I am using SSRS 2008 R2.

I need functionality in my report like, on clicking a particular bar graph column, it should display details of that bar in a pop up window with a close button on top of it, as in SAP BO. I searched a lot but couldn't get the hints. Finally I am just confused whether is it possible in SSRS or not ? If yes, then how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think this kind of graph or functionality exist in SSRS yet but you can look at the third party graph technology like [Dundas](http://www.dundas.com/dashboard/features/microsoft-bi-technology/).

[DEMO](http://www.dundas.com/dashboard/get-live-demo/)

might be the right choose fot you